# when i export my blend project to fbx it loses certain material properties like glow, transparency and glasss effect

Tags: materials, blend-files, .fbx

When it gets exported the materials get "downgraded" and i dont know how to fix it. I have searched every where and tried diferent versions of blender still nothing. If you need any info just ask me and i will give more, Any help out there?

Comment: material nodes will not be exported to fbx, just "plain" color. You can search for similar questions here.

Comment: what do i do now i just want to export it to ue4

Comment: You need to bake your textures to a final image